# struct tm tm_isdst disagrees with BST

Tags: c, datetime, c++builder

I'm in the UK. I'm using C++ builder 10.2 with the clang compiler. The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
  typedef char _TCHAR;
  #define _tmain main
#endif

int _tmain()
{

    printf("TZ set = %s\r\n",putenv("TZ=Europe/London")==0 ? "true" : "false");
    printf("TZ=%s\r\n",getenv("TZ"));

    for (int dst = 0, year = 2017; year <= 2023; year++)
        for (int mon = 1; mon <= 12; mon++)
            for (int mday = 1; mday <= 31; mday++)
            {
                struct tm st = { 0, 0, 12, mday, mon - 1, year - 1900 };
                st.tm_isdst=-1;
                time_t tt = mktime(&st); // this sets the tm_isdst to 1 or 0
                if (st.tm_isdst != dst)
                {
                    dst = st.tm_isdst;
                    printf("%02d/%02d/%d (%ld) ", mday - !dst, mon, year, tt-(!dst)*24*60*60);
                    if (!dst) printf("\r\n");
                }
            }
    getch();
}
```

produces the following output

```
12/03/2017 (1489316400)   04/11/2017 (1509796800)
11/03/2018 (1520766000)   03/11/2018 (1541246400)
10/03/2019 (1552215600)   02/11/2019 (1572696000)
08/03/2020 (1583665200)   00/11/2020 (1604145600)
14/03/2021 (1615719600)   06/11/2021 (1636200000)
13/03/2022 (1647169200)   05/11/2022 (1667649600)
12/03/2023 (1678618800)   04/11/2023 (1699099200)
```

(The 00/11/2020 should be 30/10/2020 but I don't see the point of complicating the code to correct it).

The problem is the above dates are totally at odds with British Summer Time as listed by wiki -

```
2017 26 March 29 October 
2018 25 March 28 October 
2019 31 March 27 October 
2020 29 March 25 October 
2021 28 March 31 October 
2022 27 March 30 October 
2023 26 March 29 October
```

The BST starting dates provided by my code (left hand side) return unix timestamps that are 3600 secs (1 hour) out. From comments below it seems the output would be all correct if my TZ was set to Canadian-American but it's set to London.

EDIT: I'm rephrasing the question. HITF do you get the code above to use the time zone as set in the Windows 10 settings? No matter what I set the time zone to it still comes up with similar dates. The only time I get a correct answer is if I specifically make the time zone (UTC-8.00) Pacific Time (US & Canada). It seems to use that time zone regardless of the one selected in settings. It's been bad enough waking up during this lockdown and not knowing what day it is. Now I don't even know what time zone it is.

EDIT2: I added the lines

```
printf("TZ set = %s\r\n",putenv("TZ=Europe/London")==0 ? "true" : "false");
printf("TZ=%s\r\n",getenv("TZ"));
```

to the code and while they printed

TZ set = true
TZ=Europe/London

nothing changed.

Comment: Don't do this: `struct tm st = {0, 0, 12, ...};` because [C11 7.27](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27): "The tm structure shall contain at least the following members, **in any order**." Initialize to `0` (`struct tm st = {0};`), then set each member (if not zero) individually (`st.tm_hour = 12; ...`).

Comment: Those dates are the first and last date of Canadian-American DST. Check what TZ you have specified.

Comment: Note that you are expected to set `st.tm_isdst` before calling `mktime`. Presumably, this value is used during the overlapped ("fall back") hour in a change out of DST.

Comment: @pmg Changed, although it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @ikegami My system TZ is set to UTC+0.00 (Dublin, Edinburgh, London etc.). Do I have to inform my programme of this? I assumed it took it direct from the system. I inserted the line st.tm_isdst=-1; before the mktime call but no difference to the result. Interesting that it's agreeing with CAN_America DST though.

Comment: Also initialize with `.tm_isdst = -1`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, I already mentioned it needs to be initialized and why :)

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to change the entire system's time zone in order to convert to other time zones like you are planning on doing? No. The time zone is initialized using `tzset()`, which uses the `TZ` env var, which starts off as the system setting. [Output](https://pastebin.com/eeq9KW5g) of your program for different TZ values (not even calling `tzset()` explicitly). (I removed the conio and TCHAR stuff).

Comment: @ikegami I have been changing my system TZ using the windows 10 settings. I've no idea how to do it programmatically. I'm looking it up now but so far not much of it makes sense to me.

Comment: @ikegami I tried the code on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tzset?view=vs-2019 but get 3 unresolved external messages (__get_daylight/timezone/tzname) despite having the same includes.

Comment: @ikegami Time Zone does not dictate DST though - it is country specific; for that you need `setlocale()`.

Comment: @Clifford, It does. And it's actually far finer-grained than country specific. For example, most of Saskatchewan doesn't use DST, so it has its own tz (`America/Regina`) distinct from the `America/Winnipeg` that would otherwise be used.

Comment: @ikegami : I see - I stand corrected.  I was thinking of the concept of longitudinal time-zones in general, rather then the TZ environment variable or `tzset()`.  Good point.

Comment: @Clifford, I think you're thinking of time zone *offsets*

Comment: @ikegami - yep - although perhaps I was not thinking at all.  I was about to delete my comment until you responded to it.  Now I am doomed to look dumb forever!

Comment: @ikegami OP code does set `.tm_isdst` to 0 given `st={0,0,12,mday,mon-1,year-1900}`.  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61989232/struct-tm-tm-isdst-disagrees-with-bst#comment109638788_61989232)  implies it is not set - there is no partial initialization in C.  [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61989232/struct-tm-tm-isdst-disagrees-with-bst#comment109639673_61989232) directs the preferred value to use.  Prior comments are quiet on that.

Comment: @Clifford. I tried setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_GB") to see what would happen but it returned NULL suggesting it was unable to be set. No idea why but it was worth a try. I can't see why it doesn't work with my original code. TZ is definitely set to UTC+0.00.

Comment: UTC+0:00 would have no DST. It's a specific offset.

Comment: @ikegama Sorry, I meant (UTC+0.00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London.

Comment: @NoComprende : I believe the locale name is "en-GB" rather than "en _GB".

Comment: @Clifford Changed it but still returned NULL :-(

Comment: Re the update, you need to call `tzset()`  after changing the env

Comment: @ikegami. Thanks but I had already tried that. It didn't make any difference to the output. Still the Canadian .. DST.

Answer (score 2):

Those dates are the first and last date of Canadian-American DST. Check what time zone is specified by the `TZ` environment variable.

Other issues:

- You assume the order of fields in `struct tm`, but the order isn't specified by the language.
- You don't initialize the `tm_isdst` field correctly. `-1` should be used for if it's unknown whether DST is being used or not. The value is presumably used to handle the overlapped ("fall back") hours in a change out of DST.
- Your code assumes the switch to DST happens earlier in the year than the switch from DST, but it would be the opposite in the southern hemisphere.

Program with these issues fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
   int dst = -1, dst_syear, dst_smon, dst_smday;
   for (int year=2017; year<=2023; ++year) {
      for (int mon=1; mon<=12; ++mon) {
         for (int mday=1; mday<=31; ++mday) {
            // Note that using .tm_isdst = -1 instead of the proper value 
            // will cause mktime to fail during one of the overlapped hours
            // of a "fall back" change from DST.
            struct tm st = {
               .tm_year  = year-1900,
               .tm_mon   = mon-1,
               .tm_mday  = mday,
               .tm_hour  = 12,
               .tm_isdst = -1,
            };

            mktime(&st);  // This sets the tm_isdst to 1 or 0

            if (dst == -1) {
               if (st.tm_isdst == 0) {
                  dst = 0;
               }
            } else {
               if (st.tm_isdst != dst) {
                  dst = st.tm_isdst;
                  if (st.tm_isdst) {
                     dst_syear = year;
                     dst_smon  = mon;
                     dst_smday = mday;
                  } else {
                     printf("%d-%02d-%02d %d-%02d-%02d\n",
                        dst_syear, dst_smon, dst_smday,
                        year, mon, mday);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ TZ=Europe/London ./a
2017-03-26 2017-10-29
2018-03-25 2018-10-28
2019-03-31 2019-10-27
2020-03-29 2020-10-25
2021-03-28 2021-10-31
2022-03-27 2022-10-30
2023-03-26 2023-10-29

$ TZ=America/Toronto ./a
2017-03-12 2017-11-05
2018-03-11 2018-11-04
2019-03-10 2019-11-03
2020-03-08 2020-11-01
2021-03-14 2021-11-07
2022-03-13 2022-11-06
2023-03-12 2023-11-05

$ TZ=Australia/Sydney ./a
2017-09-31 2018-04-01
2018-10-07 2019-04-07
2019-10-06 2020-04-05
2020-10-04 2021-04-04
2021-10-03 2022-04-03
2022-10-02 2023-04-02
```

Comment: Answer replaced.

Comment: *You don't initialize all the fields in the `struct tm`*: if an initializer is present, all fields are initialized. The fields are initialized in the order of members, which indeed is not specified in the C Standard, and any fields not present in the initializer are set to 0.

Comment: @chqrlie, Thank you. Didn't know. Fixed. The OP is apparently using Windows, which falls outside of POSIX.

Comment: Sorry, it is not even specified by POSIX: it says the structure must contain at least these fields, which is insufficient to ensure they are at the beginning of the structure

Comment: @ikegami I've been responding to comments below my OP without even noticing this answer. Thanks for your time but I get the same answer as In my OP except the dates on the rhs are 1 day later. I take it you're not on windows? I even tried rebooting my laptop in case the TZ hadn't registered or something.

Comment: Just set my TZ to (UTC+12.00) Fiji and still got the exact same wrong answer.

Comment: Re "*take it you're not on windows?*", I am, but I don't have a C compiler on my Windows system (discounting unix environments such as WSL and Cygwin).

Comment: Re "*I get the same answer as In my OP except the dates on the rhs are 1 day later*", Expected. Your prog shows the last full date of DST, while mine shows the starting date of standard time. That way, I don't have get the 0th of Nov like your does, and it handles the fact that DST switches often happen at a time other than midnight

Comment: @ikegama Incidentally I pasted your code into https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php and again there was no output suggesting tm_isdst was always zero.

Comment: I'm afraid it's bedtime in Scotland (for old gits at least) so thanks for everyone's help especially ikegama. Will look in tomorrow morning but will have a rope on standby. :-(

Comment: That's because its TZ is set to `UTC`, which doesn't has DST. If you change the tz, you get [correct results](http://tpcg.io/TG2m1p2U)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for clearing that up. Unfortunately if I add those 2 env related lines to my code I get "Unresolved external '_setenv'". I've been unable to find any #include that accommodates it. I've changed my code to also display the unix timestamp and altered your code within the online compiler to print out all mktime values. By comparing I can confirm the returned timestamps in my code are 3600 secs out for dates that have an incorrect isdst value. My code truly is spouting the timestamps for the Canadian_american TZ.